# Analysis by subset does not work

Tags: r, subset

I subset my data by each value on the variable 'ean' for which I first create a vector containing all unique values on this variable in mydata.

```
eans<-unique(mydata$ean)
for (i in 1:length(eans)){ 

  temp <- mydata[mydata$ean==eans[i],]

  #Data manipulations (1 example)
  table(temp$store)

  rm(temp)
}
```

For some reason, this does not give me any output and no error either... When I replace "eans[i]," by a specific ean it works though... I can't see the issue.

Comment: You can use an `lapply` to store the results in a list `lapply(unique(mydata$ean), function(x) table(mydata[mydata$ean == x,"store"]))`

Comment: Closing as duplicate. The relevant part of the answer at the link is the bit that points you to `?Control`, where it's documented that `for` returns `NULL` invisibly. Perhaps also have a look at the result of running `for(i in 1:4) i` to see that this is all about the behavior of `for` loops in general, and has pretty much nothing to do with the particular code in your example `for` loop.

Comment: My apologies, this indeed answers my question. The loop in itself works fine.

Comment: No problem. It's a good question that once puzzled me as well, back in the day!